# include/input get relative paths wrong when doing out-of-source compilation

Tags: input, include, paths

I have a document which compiles fine. I am trying to refactor it into separate files but the `input` command seems to be basing its paths relative to the *build directory* rather than the *source directory*.

My directory structure:

```
project/src/main.tex
project/build/
```

main.tex looks initially like this, simplified

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

If I do this

```
$> cd project/build
$> pdflatex ../src/main.tex
```

then I get the desired output in `project/build/` with no junk added to `project/src`, great.

Now move `\renewcommand...` into `project/src/commands.tex` and edit `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\input{commmands}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Now when I run `pdflatex` it halts on the second line:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `commands.tex' not found.
```

If I edit `main.tex` thus:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\input{../src/commands}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

then it compiles fine.

This is clearly idiotic. The source code should not care about the working directory of the compiler invocation.

How to I write `main.tex` so that it includes all other files *relative to its own path* (and for this behaviour to apply to includes-of-includes and so on) so that I can compile the document out-of-source?

Comment: As you found out, LaTeX uses its actual working directory as root for relative pathes.  Of course, you could try to work with absolute pathes: `\input{C:/project/src/commands}` should do the trick, assuming that `project/` is located in the `C:`-directory of your windows-system.  By using absolute pathes, your documents is no more portable, as with relative pathes.

Comment: Nonsense, of course it's more portable with relative paths -- what if you want to share the project, or rename some parent directory? Requiring absolute paths is madness, and so is using the working directory as root. I can't believe there's no way to change this?!?

Comment: What do you mean with "Nonsense".  I read it, that my comment makes "no sense".  I doubt, that.

Comment: Maybe `\usepackage{import}` comes to the rescue

Comment: That is not how `\input` is defined. It may not be what you expected but it is clearly not idiotic, people have worked with it that way for over 30 years. (I would not use absolute paths just use the TEXINPUTS search path, just as `\documentclass{book}` (which is `\input{book.cls}`)  just requires the local filename not a path.

Comment: @vaettchen thanks although I'm finding the explanations of `\import` to be rather vague/confusing. How is `\import{src/}{foo}` different from `\input{src/foo}`?

Comment: if you run pdftex from a different directory you will also have the problem that aux and lot files etc will be written there and so need to configure tex to be able to input files from that location.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle won't aux just etc be recreated in the new directory? What's wrong with that?

Comment: TeX needs to be able to input them which actually it will precisely because `\input` works relative to the working directory, but that is what you said you did not want to happen

Comment: I have never used `\import` but [this explanation](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Management_in_a_large_project) should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\input{commands}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

or better call the file `commands.sty` not `commands.tex` and use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{commands}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

with a calling sequence of

```
cd project/build
TEXINPUTS=../src//:
pdflatex main.tex
```